# Seed roles in an ASP.NET MVC Core project with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to seed some roles to my identity db context, when I initially create the database.

For that I tried to implement the code like it was stated here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547994/985798

I tried this in the ConfigureServices-method inside my Startup-class:
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

using this snippet:

```
var rolestore =
    new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.
        RoleStore<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole>(identityContext);

var roleManager = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager
                  <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole>(rolestore);

//use rolemanager to insert roles etc.
```

The problem is, that it seems to not work in an fresh Core-project, created with Visual Studio 2017.

It gives me the following build error:

> CS7036    There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
>   formal parameter 'roleValidators' of
>   'RoleManager.RoleManager(IRoleStore,
>   IEnumerable>, ILookupNormalizer,
>   IdentityErrorDescriber, ILogger>,
>   IHttpContextAccessor)'

Even if I use the other overload (with null values for the other parameters), the RoleManager seems to have no "Create" method anymore.

So, I am stuck at this point. What do I need to do? Has something changed in the ASP.NET MVC Core implementation of the rolemanager? Do I use something wrong?

Comment: After you get it compiled, it may prove a problem to get the Seed() executed. Afaik that's planned for EfCore 2.0 .

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Running it inside the startup should work just fine, shouldn't it? I know, it might not be the best place, but I assume it should work.

Comment: Instead of "newing" RoleManager try resolving it in `Configure` method. [Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934201/asp-net-core-identity-add-custom-user-roles-on-application-startup/39934793#39934793) and [MusicStore](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/1.0.0/src/MusicStore/Models/SampleData.cs#L22-L34)

Comment: Works for me. Like you said, you can use the IServiceCollection to retreave both your UserManager and your RoleManager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class Seed
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        var _context = provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var userManager = provider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var roleManager = provider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();


    }
}
```

Then below the majority of the code in the in the `Configure()` in `startup.cs`

```
Seed.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
```

HTH (hope that helps).

Comment: Thanks, but what does HTH mean?

Comment: HTH (hope that helps)

Comment: How do you handle the await on the async calls in a non async method?

Comment: If you added in Configure, doesn't will executed every time that a request is made?

Comment: yes but you could also check for whether or not migrations need to run which would minimize the instantiated code.

Comment: When I try and run this i get the error:  Cannot resolve scoped service 'ProjectName.Data.ApplicationDbContext' from root provider.'  Any thoughts?

Comment: @zszep I honestly don't remember, I was able to find a way to seed roles in my project(s) though.  If you need assistance let me know and I'll try and help.  Maybe open up a new question on how to seed roles/users.