# ASP.NET Core 3: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Alpha.Models.Identity.User]' from root provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.0

When I run the project, I encounter this problem:
(I've used `asp.net core 3`.)

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Alpha.Models.Identity.User]' from root provider.

How can I solve this problem?

**ApplicationDbContext class:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, 
UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
public static async Task CreateAdminAccount(IServiceProvider 
serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        UserManager<User> userManager = 
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
        RoleManager<Role> roleManager = 
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<Role>>();

        string userName = configuration["Data:AdminUser:Name"];
        string email = configuration["Data:AdminUser:Email"];
        string password = configuration["Data:AdminUser:Password"];
        string role = configuration["Data:AdminUser:Role"];

        if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName) == null)
        {
            if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role) == null)
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new Role(role));
            }

            User user = new User
            {
                Email = email,
                UserName = userName
            };
            var result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
            if (result.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Details of error:**

> An error occurred while starting the application. AggregateException:
>   One or more errors occurred. (Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Alpha.Models.Identity.User]'
>   from root provider.)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>
> InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Alpha.Models.Identity.User]'
>   from root provider.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
>
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot resolve
>   scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Alpha.Models.Identity.User]'
>   from root provider.)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions) System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(int
>   millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
>   Alpha.Web.App.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IWebHostEnvironment env) in Startup.cs
>   +
>               ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(app.ApplicationServices,
>   Configuration).Wait(); System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object
>   target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool
>   wrapExceptions) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(object instance,
>   IApplicationBuilder builder)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
>   host, CancellationToken token)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
>   host, CancellationToken token)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost
>   host) Alpha.Web.App.Program.Main(string[] args) in Program.cs
>   +
>               CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
>
> Show raw exception details InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve
>   scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Alpha.Models.Identity.User]'
>   from root provider.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceProviderEngineCallback.OnResolve(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>   Alpha.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration) in
>   ApplicationDbContext.cs
>   +
>               UserManager userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService>();
>
> Show raw exception details System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot
>   resolve scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Alpha.Models.Identity.User]'
>   from root provider.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceProviderEngineCallback.OnResolve(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Alpha.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration) in
>   E:\Archives\Projects\Alpha\Alpha.DataAccess\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line
>   92 .NET Core 3.0.0 X64 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
>   version 3.0.0-rc2.19465.2    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763    |
>   Need help?

[image: error details]

Comment: Have you followed the steps in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to register the Authentication services?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the screenshot you've included, it shows that you've got the following line in `Startup.Configure`:

```
ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(app.ApplicationServices, Configuration)
    .Wait();
```

The `IServiceProvider` instance stored in [`IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.iapplicationbuilder.applicationservices?view=aspnetcore-3.0) is the *root* service provider for your application. The error message states that it cannot resolve a *scoped* service from the *root* service provider.

This issue comes up often, but the easiest solution for your scenario is to inject `IServiceProvider` into your `Configure` method and pass that into `CreateAdminAccount`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(serviceProvider, Configuration)
        .Wait();
}
```

The instance of `IServiceProvider` that gets passed into `Configure` is *scoped*, which means that you can use it to create scoped services.

That's all you need to make this work, but it's more typical to do this type of seeding in `Program`. That keeps seeding concerns separate from configuring the pipeline and it also allows the use of `async`/`await`. Here's an example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

            await ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(serviceProvider, config);
        }

        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        // ...
}
```

You could resolve `UserManager<User>` and `RoleManager<Role>` in `Main` too, and pass those in to `CreateAdminAccount` rather than having it use the service-locator approach.