# Asp.net core MVC 6.How to disable scope verification in Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

when I try to run the line:

```
ApplicationDbContext context = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>()
```

I get presented with an error: `"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'SportsStore.Models.ApplicationDbContext' from root provider.'"`

I saw an answer to a similar question([Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider - solution to error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934704/cannot-resolve-scoped-service-from-root-provider-solution-to-error)), but idk how to do it in asp.net core mvc 6.0.

Comment: Disabling scope-validation means _sweeping a problem under the rug_ and it will only make things worse because then it will surprise you _after_ app startup. Instead, fix your `ConfigureServices` method.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    // Do something...
}
```